# AttributeError: 'Images' object has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python, string, list, class, popup

I am working with this code so I have my main code here:

```
from draw_image import Images
start = Images()
start.display_image()
start.delete_line()
start.display_image()
```

and this is my draw_image code:

```
class Images:

def image(jumper_image):
    """This function is to create the list"""
    jumper_image = []

def display_image(jumper_image):
    """This is how the user will see the image correctly through the loop"""
    jumper_image = [
        "    ___    ",
        "   /___\   ",
        "   \   /   ",
        "    \ /    ",
        "     o     ",
        "    /|\    ",
        "    / \    ",
        "           ",
        "^^^^^^^^^^^"
        ]  
    for image in jumper_image:
        print(image) 
    return jumper_image

def delete_line(jumper_image):
    """ This function is supposed to delete the first line of the jumper_image"""
    jumper_image.pop(0)
```

It seems that the delete_line function is not recognizing the list, do you guys have any idea why this is happening? or what would be a solution for this problem?

Comment: Thank you, It worked! I am new to classes so I am learning about them. I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a python constructor to initialize `jumper_image`:

```py
class Images:

  def __init__(self):
    self.jumper_image = [
        "    ___    ",
        "   /___\   ",
        "   \   /   ",
        "    \ /    ",
        "     o     ",
        "    /|\    ",
        "    / \    ",
        "           ",
        "^^^^^^^^^^^"
        ] 

  def display_image(self):
    """This is how the user will see the image correctly through the loop"""

    for image in self.jumper_image:
        print(image) 

  def delete_line(self):
    """ This function is supposed to delete the first line of the jumper_image"""
        self.jumper_image.pop(0)

start = Images()
start.display_image()
start.delete_line()
print('After deleting first value in list\n')
start.display_image()
```

```
    ___    
   /___\   
   \   /   
    \ /    
     o     
    /|\    
    / \    
           
^^^^^^^^^^^
After deleting first value in list

   /___\   
   \   /   
    \ /    
     o     
    /|\    
    / \    
           
^^^^^^^^^^^
```